# Site menu using django

Tags: python, django, menu

I want a menu on my web site.
I want this menu to be editable via django admin. So, I need to create a model for it.

Once I've created model for my menu, I can use it in my **views.py**:

```
def main(request):
    menu_items = MenuItem.objects.all()
    return direct_to_template(request, 'main.html', {'menu_items': menu_items})
```

It is ok. But... wait a minute...
If I have several pages, it will look like:

```
def main(request):
    menu_items = MenuItem.objects.all()
    return direct_to_template(request, 'main.html', {'menu_items': menu_items})

def page1(request):
    menu_items = MenuItem.objects.all()
    return direct_to_template(request, 'page1.html', {'menu_items': menu_items})

def page2(request):
    menu_items = MenuItem.objects.all()
    return direct_to_template(request, 'page2.html', {'menu_items': menu_items})`
```

Is there any way not to write the same code everytime I create new function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, create a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) and your menu will be available on every page

Inside one of your apps create a file **menu_context_processor.py** (or similar)

```
from myapp.models import MenuItem
def menu(request):
    return {'menu': MenuItem.objects.all() }
```

and add it to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR` setting in `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...,
    'myapp.menu_context_processor.menu'
)
```

and now, in every template, you will have access to `{{ menu }}`. These are used to make `{{ STATIC_URL }}` and `{{ MEDIA_URL }}' available to you throughout your application and are useful for variables you want to include everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, Timmy suggested you a Django way and it works great. By the way, I know a pythonic way that you can use decorators like this:

```
def apply_menu(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        request = args[0]
        menu_items = MenuItem.objects.all()
        vars = {'menu_items': menu_items}
        if kwargs:
            page, template_var = func(*args, **kwargs)
        else: page, template_var = func(*args)
        vars.update( template_var)
        return return direct_to_template(request, page, vars)
    return wrapper
```

And then use the decorator this way:

```
@apply_menu
def main(request):
    your_extra_vars = {}
    return 'main.html', your_extra_vars
```

Comment: hm... this way makes us to write @apply_menu under every function in views.py. It's not good, isn't it?

Comment: Exactly, This way is just some kinds of playing around with Python. The best way is Timmy solution.

Comment: By the way, using decorator really saves the job for you of checking permission.